# Xububtu trusty - cannot switch to other input methods when logged in with subsequently accounts created

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, ibus, input-method

I encounter this strange behaviour with xubuntu trusty. I have set up ibus for inputting Chinese and Japanese for the first user account created during installation. Everything works as expected. However, switching to these input methods when logged in using additional accounts subsequently created does not work. Ibus and supporting Chinese and Japanese client engines are installed and `im-config` is used to select ibus as the active configuration. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know those ibus settings are user specific, so you probably need to select the desired engines via ibus-setup for each user.